# what usually i do when i need something like popup in my facebook app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, popupwindow

I have fb app that in some-point i need the user select some picture from popup
but , now i don't allow to use popups , mainly because popup blockers .
what usually faceboop up is using ? 
can i use   modal dialogs with overlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jquery-ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), [simple modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/), or [facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/).
I am sure there are more options but these three are very common.